# how to increase performance of mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this query to check the username is already exist or not in database using ajax
so till now i hv only few records in DB bt in future username list gonna be huge so i want to improve the performance of query in such a way it will take less time to check username existence.

how can i improve following query ? is indexing on db is feasible solution for this ?

```
check.php

<?php
if(isset($_POST['user_name']))
{
$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
include("include/conn.php");
$sql_check = mysql_query("select userid from `vector`.`signup` where userid='".$user_name."'")
 or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($sql_check)>0)
{   
    echo "no";
} 
else
{
 echo "yes";
}
}
?> 

my jquery code 

<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#uname").blur(function()
    {
                $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");

        $.post("check.php",{ user_name:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data=='no') //if username not avaiable
          {
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() 
            { 

              $(this).html('This User name Already exists').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
            });     
          }
          else
          {
            $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  
            { 

              $(this).html('Username available to register').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);    
            });
          }

        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, put an index on `userid`.   (edited, yes, sorry, meant the column in the where clause.

Comment: @Adam that is not correct. @eclair you need to create an index on userid. If userid is your primary key, then an index would have been automatically created.

Comment: @Adam, I assume you meant an index on userid?!

Comment: i thought so bt any useful tutorial to do that will help

Comment: userid is primary key in my case

Comment: Wouldn't adding LIMIT 1 cause the query to stop after finding the first matching row rather than keep searching for more matches?

Comment: @mr_eclair [SQL Indexing Tutorial](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) -- if you find the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should probably add an index on the userid field. For mysql, that would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `vector`.`signup` ADD INDEX(userid);
```

**Edit**: You can use this line in the MySQL console once you're connected to the database. If you're using PHPMyAdmin, it also supports adding indexes in their GUI.

Comment: well how to do this should i use this query in above code or should fire this in mysql console

Comment: ye i did query executed successfully now how can i check my query performance is increase ??

Comment: I believe the mysql console spits out a time of the query.. you could try one in there. If you haven't already timed this, why are you worried about optimizing it already?

Answer (score 4):

Creating an index on the **userid** column of the vector.signup table will probably solve your performance issues.

As it stands you have a massive security flaw in your script. You should never inject POST data directly into a query, because you open yourself up to a SQL injection attack. You should escape your data first:

$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

You can read more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Based on other responses, userid is a primary key field and an implicit index already exists. The only other viable mechanisms available for improving performance is to append LIMIT 1 to your query, use table partitioning, or utilize integer-based primary keys.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to focus on security, performance, and organization as a developer. Here's how I would re-write your code to be easier to read and more secure. Hope it helps you out:

```
<?php

$strUsername = isset($_POST['user_name']) ? $_POST['user_name'] : NULL;

if(!empty($strUsername)) {

    require("include/conn.php"); // Consider using require_once() if it makes sense

    $objResults = mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT userid
                                FROM vector.signup
                                WHERE userid = "%s"
                                LIMIT 1', mysql_real_escape_string($strUsername)));

    if ($objResults === FALSE) {

        // Log the mysql_error() (dont show it to the user for security reasons)
        exit('Insert user friendly error message');

    } else {

        if (mysql_num_rows($objResults) === 1) {

            echo "Yes";

        } else {

            echo "No";

        }

    }

} else {

    echo "Invalid input error message";

}
?>
```

Comment: Do you receive any kind of error message or just a white screen?

Comment: using above code i'm sending to no and yes to jquery code to display message username name exists or not bt seems not working

Comment: "seems not working" doesn't really tell me much. Use the Firebug net panel to see exactly what response you're getting. If it's a blank page, it probably is related to a syntax error of sorts. My script above doesn't contain any syntax errors. I did change your "yes" and "no" to "Yes" and "No" Did you change your JavaScript to check for the capitalized versions?

Comment: ^ i modified it to small letter no and yes

Comment: What happens if you do: alert(data) in your AJAX call?

Comment: invalid input error message in alert box when i alert(data) before data=='no' condition

Comment: You did enter something in the text box before you sent it right? Add the following after the $strUsername line in the PHP file: var_dump($strUsername); exit; Now what does your alert tell you?

Comment: yes i enter 'vishwanath' in username sumting it shows string(10) vishwanath the code after if(data=='no') not executing der is prb

Comment: because if i alert after data==no nothing is alerted in alertbox

Comment: I'm retarded. There was a typo in my script above. If you copy the updated script, it should work. Sorry about that.

Comment: still i made changes u made only in !empty ? still not working

Comment: What does your alert say now?

Comment: OK, so that means that the PHP script is sending the correct data. Now, your JS should work and hit the else statement. Try adding an alert to your else statement to make sure that is being fired.

Comment: alert("hello"+ data); in else of js script alerts "hello yes" if user exists and "hello no" if new username is entered

Answer (score 1):

There are two use cases:

1)If you don't mind having list of users available to the end user who is searching for the username you can fetch the complete list in one go and use javascript function to give user the options on each key pressed.

2)If you don't want to give end user complete list ,you can be assured of the method you are using.Just have indexing on username.It will be sufficiently fast even for millions of records.

Thanks,

Shashwat

Comment: Please don't do number 1. If your table is big enough to need indexing on the name field, it certainly isn't better to dump the entire table into the data you're sending to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can delay your request to the server while the user types. The following example will call the `myAjaxFunc` function only when no key is presses for at least a second. (So no call-call-call while typing.)

```
<input type="text" name="username" onkeypress="ajaxRefresh()">

<script>
    window.ajaxTimeout = false;

    function ajaxRefresh() {
        if (window.ajaxTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(window.ajaxTimeout);
            window.ajaxTimeout = false;
        }
        window.ajaxTimeout = setTimeout(myAjaxFunc, 1000);
    }

    function myAjaxFunc() {
        // do your AJAX stuff
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot optimize the query itself, as it is just searching fo the id in a column, and that's what has to be done. but you can add an index to the column, so your dbms is prepared to search the column efficiently. and you might choose to use iso-whatever instead of utf-8. then sorting will be faster for your db, b/c the field takes less memory.